# iOS < 5 can't load twitter framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I'm using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007218/detect-ios-version-for-twitter) to detect the Twitter framework on iOS 5 devices. The problem is older devices don't have the Twitter library so I get the following error on iOS 4:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
```

How do I make an app that can use the Twitter framework on iOS 5 and use a different API on iOS 4 and below?

Comment: look to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599944/ios5-sharekit-for-twitter-issue/8601053#8601053

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to "weak link" it. Under "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries" select "Optional" for the Twitter framework:

[Weak Link Twitter.framework http://www.hypercrypt.net/images/SO10249170.png](http://www.hypercrypt.net/images/SO10249170.png)